# EDI 864 : How to identify parent file type? (810, 856 or any other)

Tags: edi, x12, edifact

I am implementing EDI (*.X12) in my application.
864 file is the file type for message exchange.
It can be used in response to any file sent from my application to my client's application.

For example:
I am sending 810 file to my client. If file has any issue with file, client will send me back 864 file with error message.

Same can be possible for 856 or any other file from my application to my client's application.

So How can I identify the original file type (810, 856 or any other) from received 864?

Like : In case of received 997 we get original file type under AK2.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the 997 FA, there are no references to other EDI document types or control numbers.

The ASN will relate to the PO number in the PRF segment.  The invoice will also reference the PO number. The 864 will have a reference to the business document that failed or needs action on.

Comment: Ok, thanks. so 864 will have a reference of original document.. Can it be in any of the segment or any fix segment or will it vary by each Trading partner?

Comment: The 864 is a Text message by the standard. It is mostly free form to convey information about a document.  You might find what you're looking for in the NTE segment.